# Will my iPhone 5 work in 12.10?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the current state of apple device (iPhone, iPod, etc.) support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support)

If I install ubuntu 12.10 how did I manage my music on my iphone 5? Does rhythmbox work with iphone? Or anything else? Music is important to me and I can't seem to find any information on this, would anyone be able to help please

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

iOS5 is not currently supported by Ubuntu. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support/89265) for a summary of which Apple Devices work and which don't!