# How can I Sync/Backup iPhone 4S (IOS 7) with ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, backup, sync, iphone

I have recently upgraded my iPhone 4S to IOS 7. I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on all my systems and due to Security reasons it is not safe to sync and backup my iPhone on other's Windows based systems with iTunes.

My question, is there any alternative for iTunes on Ubuntu or any mechanism I can use to both backup and sync my phone with my linux system ?

Methods I can came across like `Free MP3` app worked with IOS 6 only and could only sync music.

Comment: Although this question is a lot older, the situation hasn't changed as far as I know.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/305854/how-to-sync-iphone-4s-ipod-ios6-1-3-on-13-04 A jailbreak would add some options, but I don't recommend jailbreaking in general.

Answer (score 0):

and wine emulators no longer work, so sadly the best way is to create a virtual manager (Windows  7, 8, 8.1, 10) and install iTunes there.