# How can I get Rhythmbox to support 7th Gen iPod Nano?

Tags: sync, rhythmbox, ipod

I recently purchased a 7th Generation iPod Nano, and I try to get it to sync to Rhythmbox, but it only supports iPod Nano up to 6th Gen, and I don't know how to change that. I tried upgrading my distribution from 12.10 to 13.04, but it turns out that my distro was not the issue? Is there perhaps an update for Rhythmbox that fixes this?

Comment: try to see if `gtkpod ipod manager` works https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/gtkpod/

Comment: I installed that but only supports up to 4th Gen.

Comment: you could try to see if ifuse works https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/ifuse/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current state of apple device (iPhone, iPod, etc.) support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support)