# Ubuntu 12.4lts iPhone 5 can't mount. test this computer loops endlessly

Tags: mount, iphone

Just what the subject said.

Wife just got a new iPhone 5c iOS 7. I had pulled all the goodies off her old android (now my new android) and wanted to dump the pics and stuff back onto her new phone. 
Alas, no joy.

iphone prompts 'Trust this Compter?' I select to trust, and it just pops back up again, looping endlessly.

Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Comment: You need the newest version of libmobiledevice. Get more information here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with an iPhone 4S running the latest iOS 7 and getting the same issue. Luckily I found a workaround:

- Plug in your phone
- On your phone, click the "Trust" option
- On your Ubuntu system, click the "OK" on the popup dialog
  (You should see the iphone get mounted)
- On your Ubuntu system, click the "OK" on the next dialog that says something like "do you want to continue?"

Now ignore the loop!

You should be able to manually navigate to your iPhone within Ubuntu and see all the usual iphone folders, such as DCIM, and access items with no issues.

Hope this works for others until there's a fix!