# Syncing Ipod Shuffle

Tags: ipod

Hello i've tried to sync my ipod shuffle (latest gen) for 2 hours now...

I've tried banshee (I can put music on my device but not listening to it, "use itunes blablabla"), I've tried gtkpod (not launching), Floola (no ipod connected).

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Well, what version of Ubuntu? And what do you mean by gtkpod not launching? Does it segfault?

Comment: 13.04. I mean that after typing gtkpod in a terminal a small window open with the logo of the program but no program after that. I don't know what segfault means.

Comment: Launch gtkpod from a terminal, does it output errors on startup?

Comment: @EliahKagan This is the third iQuestion you've VTC as duplicate tonight. However the dupe is from 2011 and this question and the last is from 2014. Would an answer from 2011 still apply in 2014?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Maybe there's a better dupe target for them. I think potentially a specific technical question about libimobiledevice could be answered and we shouldn't automatically dupe that sort of question. But isn't the general answer to the question of how to access features of any particular Apple device on any GNU/Linux OS (besides as a removable disk) still that hopefully libimobiledevice supports and isn't currently broken for it? As you likely know, I have no technical knowledge about libimobiledevice, so I must admit that I could well be wrong. ...Can new answers really be given?

Comment: @EliahKagan You can take that dupe from 2011 and add your own answer or update an existing answer to modern times. I've seen it done many times.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix As far as I know, [Jon's](https://askubuntu.com/a/87394) and [Tom Brossman's](https://askubuntu.com/a/89265/22949) answers to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support) are still accurate and convey the fragmentary nature of Apple device usability ([as does Thomas Ward's answer on this other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/866155)). Do we have answers to general questions about whether or not an Apple mobile device can be used from Ubuntu and how to do it that should be updated or improved?

Comment: @EliahKagan As a general rule of thumb I think if the iDevice is using iOS 10 and the Ubuntu version is 16.04, but the Q&A in question is much much older then updated answers are warranted. You can even take a Ubuntu 12.04 answer and edit it to say "This works in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 as well".

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple: Use Amarok.
`sudo apt-get install amarok`

It is a music player and music manager from the KDE suite.

Once you install it, connect the iPod and it would appear as a local device (with ipod somewhere in its name). Before you can sync, you need to setup your local library. For this: from settings menu, go to Configure Amarok, and then in the collections tab, make sure you tick your local music folder.

[image]

Perform full collection rescan by going to Tools menu, and Update Collection.

Now coming back to the iPod section in the left hand side pane, if you right click on an artist/album/genre/song, it would allow you to copy to the local collection. Vice-a-versa, in local collection, if you right click on any artist/album/genre/song, it would allow you to copy it to your ipod.

Refer http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4791/how-to-use-amarok-to-manage-your-ipod/ for more detailed info on this.

Update: Just read your question once again. If this was prompting you to sell your ipod Shuffle, then definitely no need to do that anymore :) .

Comment: amarok does not recognise my device.