# iOS device contents e.g. "Pictures", "Documents" no longer accessible under Ubuntu

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Yesterday I updated my iPhone 6s to iOS 10, and now can't see "Documents" mount that allowed to access folders of individual apps when I was running iOS 9. My iPad which still runs iOS 9 mounts photos and documents so I can easily add films to VLC on iPad etc. How can I get the same behavior with iPhone running iOS 10?

I did install libimobiledevice1.2 but still no effect.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Well it did work yesterday on ubuntu and I want the same behavior today.

Comment: Do you mean you can't access the "Documents" folder on your iPhone when it is connected to your Ubuntu computer, from your Ubuntu computer?

Comment: It is possible that Apple patched iOS 10 so that this feature doesn't work anymore, likely because they want people to use iTunes exclusively.  I remember the same thing happened to my iPod Touch many years ago after an iOS update and it took a while for libmobiledevices to catch back up with Apple.

Comment: @ThomasWard No when I connect my ipad(or iPhone yesterday) there would be 2 mounts, 1 with DCIM containing photos and the other one with App folders for example VLC folder where I could put movies directly there. Here is [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/s35sLT2.png)

Comment: @MichaelLindman from libimobiledevice's page >>05.07.2016: Yep, libimobiledevice works with iOS 10.

Comment: Just thought i'd mention it as I had a similar issue to this in the past with libimobiledevice on my iPod Touch.

Comment: @polyx The upstream changelogs would apply to the latest versions not necessarily what's in the repositories.  16.04 probably doesn't have the latest version of the `libimobiledevice` libraries.  If you installed latest from upstream then you need to contact the developers and indicate it isn't working as advertised and wait for a bug fix. (Apple could have made an unexpected change between beta testing and release)

Comment: Yes I built from sources so should be as new as it gets, already submitted issue on their github

Comment: Libimobiledevice hasn't been updated. This bug has been reported, and you may want to click "This bug affects me" at the top of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666 if this happens for you too.

Comment: This applies only to the package in the repos, and not the upstream latest version the OP is using.

Comment: How about downgrading iOS?

Comment: @polyx I'm sorry that your question was closed unfairly as "off-topic" (specifying that  "This is not about Ubuntu...") although this is a problem experienced in Ubuntu! It's actually a bug as mentioned below. However, perhaps some workarounds may be suggested/discussed here as it may take a long time until this recurring bug is resolved.

Comment: BTW I also experience this problem with **iOS 9.3.5** (iPad) as well as **iOS 10.2** (iPhone) - probably due to a recent update to iOS 9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current state of apple device (iPhone, iPod, etc.) support?](/q/83484/175814)

Comment: @xangua you must not own Apple devices.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support because the user already knows that İOS devices have a limited support under Linux, but the question is how users can enjoy that limited support (transfer of user image, video, etc. files) again after the latest Apple updates apparently rendered that limited support dysfunctional.

Comment: This problem can be tracked here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666 Please mark "it affects me" to **support the bug report**. And here is a **temporary workaround** :  https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access iOS camera pictures on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928750/how-do-i-access-ios-camera-pictures-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

Support for Apple devices under Linux is a long standing problem, which you can follow here: [What is the current state of apple device (iPhone, iPod, etc.) support?](https://askubuntu.com/q/83484/175814)

The specific question about **accessing (and transferring) user files** (pictures, videos, documents, etc.) which was possible until recently, but which is no longer after latest iOS updates, seems to require a new update to the **libimobiledevice** package which can be followed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666  And clicking https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libimobiledevice/+bug/1623666/+affectsmetoo will allow the user to keep informed about developments in this regard.

Meanwhile, there are a number of **workarounds** (e.g. see the above-mentioned bug report discussions) enabling users to implement a **temporary solution**, which might be a little less user-friendly...

Comment: In other words, *never* update an iOS device if you want it to work well...  similar issues had popped up in earlier iOS releases as well.