# Apple iPhone 7 - Importing Pictures to Laptop Linux Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, iphone, gthumb

I have A laptop with Ubuntu 17.04 & installed Gthumb, I need to sync my phone and remove the photos because I'm running low on space, but the PC isn't recognizing there are pictures.

Is there a specific way to do this? I'm open to any other software suggestions as well.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: What is the computer saying about the pictures?

Answer (score 0):

First please look at this issue mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824991/ios-device-contents-e-g-pictures-documents-no-longer-accessible-under-ubun), then use this method to try to mount it:

1. Open a terminal window
2. Run this command, (it automates the process):

   ```
   curl -O https://www.signalnine.org/downloads/iphone.sh && so sh iphone.sh && dmesg | grep ipheth && idevicepair pair && ifuse /media/iPhone
   ```
3. Launch `nautilus` and `iphone` should be seen the left pane.
4. Unmount it with:

   ```
   fusermount -u /media/iPhone/

   idevicepair unpair
   ```
5. If you have rooted your phone you can mount the root filesystem with the following command:

   ```
   ifuse /media/iPhone/ --root
   ```

Source:

https://www.signalnine.org/mount-iphone-7-ubuntu-17-04/

#### WARNING

Don't own an iPhone, so not tested.